# Is MaxValue an unreliable function?

Tags: maximize

I have tried to compute the maximum of this function

```
MaxValue[Abs[62853.16989532622/(62853.16989532622 + 1. s)] /. 
   s -> I*w /. w -> 2 \[Pi]*f*1000, f]
```

Mathematica computes -1. It makes zero sense, this is an absolute value function... Is MaxValue unreliable? What function is the best to determine a maximum in Mathematica?

Comment: In MMA 13.2 with a fresh kernel I get `1.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that was fixed in more recent versions of Mathematica. I can reproduce it in 13.1.

To answer your question about reliability:

No, there is no reason to avoid `MaxValue`. However, there are good practices that you can follow that reduce the risk of problems.

- You have complex expressions. The maximum is 1 only when `f` is real, which is implicit here. Use `ComplexExpand` to get rid of explicitly imaginary expressions. This will get you the correct result.
- Generally, if you are looking to do symbolic computations, avoid inexact numbers. When `Rationalize`ing your expression, I get no result at all, which is better than a wrong result.
- If you are looking to do numerical computations, use explicitly numerical functions such as `NMaxValue` (doesn't help here) of `FindMaxValue` (it does).

Keep in mind that all software has bugs, especially complex software such as computer algebra systems. Always double-check your results.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll update my Mathematica version, I have the 12.3. version